# Einstein summation convention for symbolic vector calculus

Tags: summation, vector-calculus, indexed-variable

I am trying to do some vector calculus in Mathematica in index notation form because it gives a clear result that can be compared to pen and paper calculations. Since there is no built in Einstein summation convention this makes life rather difficult. I think I'm doing things the right way but if there is a better way please let me know!

I wish to evaluate vector derivatives of the tensor denoted $G$.
Using the first of the linked questions below I make the definitions

```
R /: D[R, R[a_], NonConstants -> {R}] := R[a]/R
R /: D[R[a_], R[b_], NonConstants -> {R}] := KroneckerDelta[a, b]
G = KroneckerDelta[a, b]/R + TensorProduct[R[a], R[b]]/R^3
```

And evaluate

```
D[G, R[c], NonConstants -> {R}] // FullSimplify
```

So far so good, but suppose I wish to evaluate the Laplacian.

```
D[G, R[c], R[d], NonConstants -> {R}] //. d -> c // TensorExpand
```

Now we get terms like `R[c]^2` that should automatically evaluate to `R^2`. This is not a problem, just add the lines

```
R /: R[a_] R[a_] := R^2
R /: R[a_] KroneckerDelta[a_, b_] := R[b]
```

And this works. However there are also terms like $\delta_{a,c}\delta_{b,c}$ that I want to automatically contract to $\delta_{a,b}$. These is no way to set a tag for `KroneckerDelta` since it is protected. Similarly if I want to take curls using the Levi Civita tensor this is going to get very ugly.

Tl;dr I have defined symbolic derivatives of tensors according to the first linked question since this allows me to get a result that I can visually compare to analytics. However I would also like to be able to automatically sum over all repeated indices. Is there a good way to do this? Thanks in advance!

[Cartesian tensor gradient](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143409/cartesian-tensor-gradient)

[symbolic summation involving kronecker delta](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95946/symbolic-summation-involving-kronecker-delta?rq=1)

[Implementing Einstein's summation convention for a particular case](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129554/implementing-einsteins-summation-convention-for-a-particular-case)

**EDIT: adding Levi-Civita functionality**

I whipped up the ability to use the Levi-Civita tensor symbolically and have it work correctly (as far as I have tested). First its essential that $\delta_{a,a} = d = 3$ instead of 1 then I add total antisymmetry by modifying this question on [totally antisymmetric functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137862/totally-antisymmetric-function).

```
Unprotect[KroneckerDelta]; KroneckerDelta /: 
 KroneckerDelta[a_, a_] := 3;
leviC /: MakeBoxes[leviC[a_, b_, c_], fmt_] := 
 MakeBoxes[Subscript[\[CurlyEpsilon], a, b, c], fmt]
leviC[a__] := Signature[{a}] (leviC @@ Sort@{a}) /; ! OrderedQ[{a}];
leviC[a__] := 0 /; ! DuplicateFreeQ[{a}];
```

Finally the Levi-Civita replacement rules are defined by

```
leviCrules := {leviC[indi_, indj_, indk_] leviC[indl_, indm_, 
     indn_] :> 
   KroneckerDelta[indi, 
      indl] (KroneckerDelta[indj, indm] KroneckerDelta[indk, indn] - 
       KroneckerDelta[indj, indn] KroneckerDelta[indk, indm]) - 
    KroneckerDelta[indi, 
      indm] (KroneckerDelta[indj, indl] KroneckerDelta[indk, indn] - 
       KroneckerDelta[indj, indn] KroneckerDelta[indk, indl]) + 
    KroneckerDelta[indi, 
      indn] (KroneckerDelta[indj, indl] KroneckerDelta[indk, indm] - 
       KroneckerDelta[indj, indm] KroneckerDelta[indk, indl]), 
  leviC[indi_indj _, indk_]^2 -> 6, 
  leviC[a___, b_, c_, d___] A_[Q___, b_, q___] A_[P___, c_, p___] :> 0}
```

Where the replacement rules here were taken from the code for [VEST](https://github.com/jonosquire/VEST).

As far as I can tell this gives all the correct behaviour required for symbolic vector calculus! :)

**Edit 2: dubious dummy index replacement**

I add the rule

```
   A_[Q___, c__, q___] B_[P___, c__, p___] :> 
     A[Q, dummy, q] B[P, dummy, p]
```

so that Mathematica can recognize repeated indices.However this is dangerous for the obvious reason that $v_a v_a w_b w_b = v_a w_a v_b w_b$ in this scheme but I have been unable to do rule replacement such that each time the pattern is matched the dummy index is replaced by dummyi+1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First let me remark that you can unprotect symbols by doing `Unprotect[symbol]`, and then you can define whatever you want to it. This is however not always advised.

The way I usually deal with index contractions is to define a list of replacement rules

```
rules = {δ[X_, X_] :> d, 
 δ[X_, Y_]^2 :> d, δ[X_, Y_] δ[Y_, Z_] :> δ[X,Z],
 δ[X_, Y_] A_[a___, Y_, b___] :> A[a, X, b]};
```

which can then be applied to `expr` as `expr//.rules`. Actually often times if you have ugly expressions Mathematica won't recognize patterns. To avoid that one can define a function that not only replaces repeatedly but expands every time. For example

```
ReplaceExpand[expr_, rule_] := FixedPoint[Expand[#] /. rule &, expr];
```

---

*Edit*

I forgot a few things. First for this to work `δ[X, Y]` must be defined as an `Orderless` symbol

```
SetAttributes[δ,Orderless];
```

Second, the question also needed the Levi Civita tensor. Here is an implementation that I use (for four dimensions). The rules I define use `OrderlessPatternSequence` in order to deal with all possible ordering of the indices, but at the same time keeping track of the right signature. Here is the idea: if you define a rule like

```
A[x:OrderlessPatternSequence[a_,b_]] B[y:OrderlessPatternSequence[a_,b_]] :> f[x,y]
```

this will match both `A[a,b]B[a,b]` and `A[a,b]B[b,a]` but `x` and `y` will contain the right ordering. And if you want to know the signature of the permutation of `a,b` with respect to, say, `x` you can call `Signature[PermutationList[FindPermutation[{x},{a,b}]]]`. I'll write down examples. If four indices are contracted.

```
ε4[x:OrderlessPatternSequence[μ_,ν_,ρ_,λ_]]ε4[μ_,ν_,ρ_,λ_] :> -24*Signature[PermutationList[FindPermutation[{x},{μ,ν,ρ,λ}]]]
```

If three

```
ε4[x:OrderlessPatternSequence[μ_,ν_,ρ_,λ_]]ε4[y:OrderlessPatternSequence[κ_,ν_,ρ_,λ_]] :> -6*δ[μ,κ]*Signature[PermutationList[FindPermutation[{x},{μ,ν,ρ,λ}]]]*Signature[PermutationList[FindPermutation[{y},{κ,ν,ρ,λ}]]]
```

If two

```
ε4[x:OrderlessPatternSequence[μ_,ν_,ρ_,λ_]] ε4[y:OrderlessPatternSequence[κ_,τ_,ρ_,λ_]] :> -2*Det[Table[δ[ii,jj],{ii,{μ,ν}},{jj,{κ,τ}}]]*Signature[PermutationList[FindPermutation[{x},{μ,ν,ρ,λ}]]]*Signature[PermutationList[FindPermutation[{y},{κ,τ,ρ,λ}]]]
```

Hopefully you get the picture, if less indices are contracted you need a similar expression for the determinant of δ.

---

In my opinion, neither this is the best way possible. I don't know if this is going to be useful for you, but there is a very convenient formalism that gets rid of indices. Let me explain how it goes: In order to describe a bunch of vectors $x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_n^{a_n}$ with free indices $a_1\ldots a_n$, introduce auxiliary polarizations $w_1^{a_1}\cdots w_n^{a_n}$ that contracts those indices. You will end up with expressions involving only scalar products $w_i\cdot w_j$, $x_i\cdot w_j$ and $x_i\cdot x_j$. It's easy to recover the initial expressions since
    $$
w_i\cdot w_j\to\delta^{a_ia_j}\,,\qquad
x_i\cdot w_j\to x_i^{a_j}\,,\qquad
x_i\cdot x_j\to x_i^b x_j^b\,.
$$
This is also convenient in that you don't have to come up with a new name of indices when they are summed over. If you have several $x$'s that are equal and you want to enforce the fact that their indices are symmetrized, you can contract all of them with the same $w$. So how to do it concretely?

**Define the constants**

You can define a function `ConstQ` that tells Mathematica what is a constant and what is a vector, in order to define linearity over them. These definitions should do the trick.

```
ConstQ[x_?NumberQ] := True;
ConstQ[x_Plus] := And @@ (ConstQ[#] & /@ x);
ConstQ[x_Times] := And @@ (ConstQ[#] & /@ x);
```

To which one can add any number of custom symbols with `TagSet`, e.g.

```
A /: ConstQ[A] := True;
```

will take `A` out of every linear operator. Similarly define what is a scalar, i.e. a fully contracted expression

```
ScalarQ[x_Power] := True;
ScalarQ[x_CenterDot] := True;
ScalarQ[x_?ConstQ] := True;
```

As you see I used the function `CenterDot`. This is the function that we are going to use for defining our scalar product. You can also come up with any name, it's just that `CenterDot` has a nicer built in appearance.

**Define the scalar product**

We need to define its linearity properties and the fact that it's symmetric:

```
SetAttributes[CenterDot, Orderless];
CenterDot[a_,b_Plus] := Plus @@ (CenterDot[a,#] & /@ b);
CenterDot[a_,c_*d_] /; ScalarQ[c] := c*CenterDot[a,d];
CenterDot[0,x_] := 0;
```

`CenterDot` has no built in meaning other than the fact that it looks like $a\cdot b$ and it can be entered as `esc.esc`.

**Define the derivatives**

I will not be using `D` as a derivative. Rather I will define an operator `d[w,x,expr]` that performs
    $$
w^a\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}(\mathrm{expr})\,,
$$
in the spirit of leaving no free indices around. This set of rules defines linearity

```
d[w_, x_, expr_Plus] := Plus @@ (d[w, x, #] & /@ List @@ expr);
d[w_, x_, y_?ConstQ] := 0;
```

See? `ConstQ` is useful now. This set of rules is the Leibniz rule for product and powers

```
d[w_, x_, expr_Times] :=   Plus @@ Table[MapAt[d[w, x, #] &, expr,i],{i, 1, Length[List @@ expr]}];
d[w_, x_, expr_^power_] := power expr^(power - 1) d[w, x, expr];
```

and this final set of rules actually defines the action on scalar products

```
d[w_, x_, CenterDot[x_,x_]] := 2 CenterDot[x,w];
d[w_, x_, CenterDot[x_,y_]] /; y =!= x := CenterDot[y,w];
d[w_, x_, CenterDot[y_,z_]] /; y =!= x && z =!= x := 0;
```

**Define the Laplacian**

This introduces a new thing: removing auxiliary polarizations. Let me explain: in order to do the Laplacian we can differentiate with two different new polarizations
$$
w^b\frac{\partial}{\partial x^b}w^a\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}(\mathrm{expr})\,,
$$
and then replace $w^a w^b \to \delta^{ab}$. This function does exactly that

```
dSq[x_, expr_] := Expand[d[v, x, d[w, x, expr]]] //. 
 {CenterDot[v,w] -> dimensions, CenterDot[e_,v] CenterDot[f_,w] :> CenterDot[e,f]};
```

where `dimensions` is the dimension of the space.

As a bonus you can very easily check that $|x-y|^{(2-D)/2}$ is harmonic in $D$ dimensions.

```
Simplify[dSq[x, (CenterDot[x,x])^((2 - dimensions)/2)]]
```

> 0

Comment: This is a great answer but I still have a couple questions.

First I suppose your variables dimensions and dim should be equal and TagSet to be constants. In addition I am left with terms that look like d[w,x,x] since we have not defined a rule for this term. The problem I guess is that because we have left out indicies we have no idea if this term $= \delta_{a,b}$ or $dim$.

Comment: P.S the first part of your answer works for what I want, thank you! :)
P.P.S except for rules defining replacement for the levi civita tensor. I am writing them now and will add them in an edit.

Comment: You shouldn't get `d[w,x,x]` because all expressions need to be scalar products. If you want to deal with `x` alone you need to contract it with `w`. I also edited the first part adding the Levi Civita, so you can see how I implement it.